# sudo to a different user and run command as that user

Tags: shell, sudo, user-profile, login-script, .profile

consider this sudo command below

```
sudo -iu bigadmin
```

bigadmin is a generic user that all users sudo to, to do stuff with privileged access. 
Now the problem is it a shared user like I mentioned. So any kind of profile customization isn't gonna work .

What I am trying to do is  for the sessions I establish- I want to run a script that has all my variables inside. so when I sudo it should do these things

```
sudo -iu bigadmin ; . ./mycustomshell.sh
```

How's this best done.

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure that all the variables in `mycustomshell.sh` are exported. Then, source it first, *then* run `sudo -iu bigadmin`, so that the shell started by `sudo` inherits the variables exported by `mycustomshell`.

Another option is to invoke `bash` as

```
sudo -iu bigadmin bash --rcfile mycustomshell.sh
```

However, this causes `bash` to ignore `.bashrc`, so you may want to source `.bashrc` explicitly at the beginning of `mycustomershell.sh` to compensate.

Comment: I tried the 1st one source /home/bigadmin/getin.ksh - no such file or directory

Comment: whats happening is that the standard user cannot see the elevated users directories or even know if its there but the visa versa is poss.

Comment: I voted up every answer I got . If you think this was a good question worth some wits ..you could do the same

Answer (score 1):

This bash command useful for a shell script. It runs a sudo password that given as parameter, and add a line at the end of given file.

```
echo $password | echo 'net.ipv4.ping_group_range=0 2147483647' |  sudo -S tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your command to help the future readers understand what has been done?